# How to correctly use Camera widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera

Camera usage is clearly documented at [official document](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera). It tells you to initiate camera from the `Future<void> main() async` which is the main entry point of the whole application. (correct me if this is wrong).  After that, the initialised camera is then passed down to the home page widget. This is all that official document tell us. But obviously, this isn't close enough to real-world cases. Rarely there is an application needs to open camera on the very first running.

This confuses me a lot. I can get this to work by passing down down this camera object to whatever pages that actually required it. Or maybe put it into a global state management like redux. But is this the correct way to use camera?

More ideally, if possible, I think it's the duty of a page/widget that needs camera to initiate everything rather than at the `main()` function.

Any suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `Camera` plugin where you need it not in the main function. docs just give us an example of how to do that not where to.